# How to use qRegisterMetaType instead of Q_ENUM?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

This is my class that contains Q_ENUM. I need to use Q_ENUM because of Im using QVariant. Reason being in my application, there is a section where we call qRegisterMetaType and if its possible, we would like to register metatype in only 1 location.

Is it possible to use qRegisterMetaType instead of Q_ENUM? Are there performance reason to?

```
class MyEnums : public QObject
{
    public:
        enum class SettingType
        {
            Integer,
            String,
            Boolean,
            Float,
            Double,
            Enum,
        };

        Q_ENUM(SettingType)
};
```

Comment: "Reason being in my application, there is a section where we call qRegisterMetaType and if its possible, we would like to register metatype in only 1 location."

Answer (score 3):

1. You do not need to call `qRegisterMetaType()` to use a type with `QVariant`. In general, you only need `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()`.
2. You only need to call `qRegisterMetaType()` if the type will be used in queued signal/slots connections, or with the `QObject::property` API. Note that for enum types, you no not even need to call `qRegisterMetaType()` in these cases.
3. To call `qRegisterMetaType()`, you still need to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()`. So using `qRegisterMetaType()` you will just trade `Q_ENUM()` for `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()`.
4. Using `Q_ENUM()` allows you to retrieve at run-time the name of an enum value:

   ```
   qDebug() << MyEnums::Integer // Will print "MyEnums::Integer" if using Q_ENUM()
                                // Will print "0" if using Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add **[Q_OBJECT](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT)** macro to your enum class, without that macro you can't declare it with **[Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)** and you need **[Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)** because without it your MetaType registered with **[qRegisterMetaType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1)** won't work with **[QVariant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html)**.

So your class declaration could look like this:

```
class MyEnums : public QObject
{
    public:
        enum class SettingType
        {
            Integer,
            String,
            Boolean,
            Float,
            Double,
            Enum,
        };

        //Q_ENUM(SettingType)
        Q_OBJECT
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyEnums::SettingType);
```

After that call: `qRegisterMetaType<MyEnums::SettingType>();` somethere before using your type.

Test it:

```
qRegisterMetaType<MyEnums::SettingType>();

auto val = MyEnums::SettingType::Double;
QVariant vt = QVariant::fromValue(val);

MyEnums::SettingType test = vt.value<MyEnums::SettingType>();

qDebug() << (test == val);
```